# Yesod is using first case as return type

Tags: haskell, yesod

thanks for your time:

The idea is that the `request` may include either

- a apple with code ( represented in integer )
- apples with codes

the handler will branch base on the input

- if it is an apple then return a string
- if it is apples ,then return a list of strings

the issue is , why Haskell compiler complains that ,it expects `[string]` instead of `[[strings]]` as return value ?

when I switch lines of

```
Apple code -> ["APPLE"++show code]
Apples codes -> map (\x -> ["APPLE"++ show x]) codes
```

into

```
Apples codes -> map (\x -> ["APPLE"++ show x]) codes
Apple code -> ["APPLE"++show code]
```

Now haskell is expecting `[[string]]` instead of `[string]` .

Is it `Yesod` make first case as `DEFAULT` return type of that handler ?

code of interest:

```
data Fruit = Apple Int
           | Apples [Int]

data Req = Req {
   apple :: Fruit
}
$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''Req)

data App = App

mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
 /show ShowAppleR POST
|]

instance Yesod App where
  yesodMiddleware = defaultYesodMiddleware

postShowAppleR :: Handler Value
postShowAppleR =  do
  runReq <- requireCheckJsonBody :: Handler Req
  returnJson $
      case (apple runReq) of
        Apple code -> ["APPLE"++show code]
        Apples codes -> map (\x -> ["APPLE"++ show x]) codes
```

full code :

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
module Main2 where

import Data.Aeson       hiding (json)
import Data.Monoid      ((<>))
import Data.Text        (Text, pack)
import GHC.Generics
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 (unpack)

import Language.Haskell.TH
import Data.Aeson.TH
import Data.Aeson.Types

import Yesod
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Network.Wai.Middleware.Cors


data Fruit = Apple Int
           | Apples [Int]

data Req = Req {
   apple :: Fruit
}
$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''Req)

data App = App

mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
 /show ShowAppleR POST
|]

instance Yesod App where
  yesodMiddleware = defaultYesodMiddleware

postShowAppleR :: Handler Value
postShowAppleR =  do
  runReq <- requireCheckJsonBody :: Handler Req
  returnJson $
      case (apple runReq) of
        Apple code -> ["APPLE"++show code]
        Apples codes -> map (\x -> ["APPLE"++ show x]) codes


main :: IO ()
main =
  do
   app <- toWaiApp App
   run 8084 $ defaultMiddlewaresNoLogging
            $ cors (const $ Just $ simpleCorsResourcePolicy
                                    { corsOrigins = Nothing
                                    , corsMethods = ["OPTIONS", "GET", "PUT", "POST"]
                                    , corsRequestHeaders = simpleHeaders })
            $ app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is that `returnJson` looks take the `FIRST` statement as return type. This issue can be solved by using two `returnJson` to wrap two return types.

```
postShowAppleR :: Handler Value
postShowAppleR =  do
  runReq <- requireCheckJsonBody :: Handler Req
  case (apple runReq) of
    Apples codes -> returnJson $ map (\x -> ["APPLE"++ show x]) codes
    Apple code -> returnJson $ ["APPLE"++show code]
```